# How to create string[*] || How to handle out string[*] parameter from Dll method?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

```
public static void GetDeviceInfoForImaging(
string iP, 
string benutzername, 
string passwort, 
out string[*] deviceInfo)
```

I have a reference which exposes this function. I'm puzzled as to how I should pass

```
out string[ * ] deviceInfo
```

to the function because it's not possible to create a variable of type string[*], is it?

The function comes from a LabVIEW .Net Interop Assembly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a String\[\*\] and how do I cast it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379202/what-is-a-string-and-how-do-i-cast-it)

Comment: c++ dll usually use byte[] terminated with a '\0' instead of a string class that c# uses.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, the `out` keyword is fatal here. The author of this COM component did not do a very good job making it usable.  Best to get in touch with him and ask him to modify his IDL so the last argument has the [out,retval] attribute.  If that is not an option then you'll have to change the interop library by hand.  Use ildasm.exe to decompile it, change the argument type to Array and put it back together with ilasm.exe

Comment: Hi Maksim Simkin, I do not see how that thread could help. I do not have a reference to a string[ * ] which I could cast. I can't even compile because I cannot pass the string[ * ] parameter to the function.

Comment: Hi Hans Passant.

I decompiled it with ildasm and found the declaration:
_[out]_ _string[...]&_ _deviceInfo_. 

Now I need to change it to: ?
_Array_ _deviceInfo_ ?

In that case, ilasm.exe returns a syntax error at compile.

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try:

```
    Array deviceInfo = (Array)(object)Document.GetCrossReferenceItems(WdReferenceType.wdRefTypeHeading);

    public static void GetDeviceInfoForImaging(
    string iP, 
    string benutzername, 
    string passwort, 
    out string[*] deviceInfo)
```

And then try this to extract values:

```
string firstElement = deviceInfo.GetValue(1);
```

Comment: which Reference do I need for this?

Comment: Yea this may not work for you since you need to reference Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word

Comment: I cant reference Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word in my Visual Studio.