# What does int[*] mean in C# under Visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

We make use of a third party dll that exposes a method taking an out NetworkStream.Data[] parameter:

```
public void Read(int elementsCount, int timeOutInMs, out Data[] array, out bool timedOut)
```

We use it in our code by passing in a NetworkStream.Data (a datatype defined in said library) array, and it compiles fine under Visual Studio 2012.

However, when compiled under Visual Studio 2017, this generates a cast error:

> Error CS1503 Argument 4: unable to cast 'out NetworkStream.Data[]' to 'out NetworkStream.Data[*]'

Decompilers such as DnSpy do indicate the same thing in the tooltip for the method, and in IL it shows the argumnt to be

```
[out] valuetype NetworkStream.Data[0...]& data
```

What does this NetworkStream.Data[*] or NetworkStream.Data[0...] mean and why does the cast fail  in VS 2017?

Comment: Seems related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379202/what-is-a-string-and-how-do-i-cast-it) but I've no experience of it myself, so I'll leave it to your judgement if it's useful or not.

Comment: It seems that `var` declaration can property pickup that non-zerobased array type, even that C# does not allow to spell it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the array has one or more lower bounds that are not zero.

For example, this code:

```
Array test = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new[] { 2 }, new[] { 2 });
Console.WriteLine(test.GetType().FullName);
```

Prints `System.Int32[*]`.

Comment: OK, that's what I gathered. Now my problem is, is it possible to define such an array in C# so that I can actually call a method that expects such an array, especially because it is an out parameter so I need to define a variable of that type to be filled by the called method.

Comment: @DenisTroller You might need to declare the parameter type as `Array`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson The problem is that for `out` parameter variable type must match exactly.

Comment: OP will need to contact the supplier of the 3rd party DLL to ask how to call it, methinks. There's something wrong here.

Comment: The main issue here is that non-zero-based arrays are NOT CLS-compliant, which gives rise to issues such as this. I imagine that the DLL is NOT written in C#.

Comment: After gathering some information, that is the answer. This is a labview project ompiled down to a .Net assembly. I will get a new version compiled with a more recent labview version.... thanks for the help !

Comment: @DennisTroller  I have exactly the same problem except I am trying to pass a string array. Which version of LabVIEW works? I'm still a bit puzzled because the LabVIEW-generated prototype for the method I am trying to call defines the parameter as 'out string[]', not 'out string[*]'.

Comment: @DennisTroller It's OK, I have answered my own question at least approximately: LabVIEW 2015 does not work, LabVIEW 2017 does. If you look at the xml file produced by the LabVIEW build the parameters are defined as string[*] with LabVIEW 2015 but plain string[] with 2017, which is of course correct as LabVIEW has zero-indexed arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It's an array with a non default lower bound, [see documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Int32___System_Int32___) on how to deal with this.

Comment: there is no mention about "non default lower bound" "[*]" or "[0.."] in the link you provided. Also, link only answers are usually discouraged - try to include the answer in the answer itself and use links as a [reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) instead.