# Cannot convert from 'System.Array' to 'int[*]'

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

In the application I was asked to develop, I must interface with a dll over which I have no control.

From the dll, I'm calling:

```
NAMESPACE.myFunction(string Name, int[*] Coordinates)
```

What is this int[*] type? Answer was easy found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52925748/what-does-int-mean-in-c-sharp-under-visual-studio-2017): it is a non-0 based array. This question briefly mentions some LabView compiled dll, which is very similar to my present case.

I was able to determine via researching that only an `Array` can be used to to have a `int32[*]` type. An easy way to prove it is to run this code:

```
Array AAA = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 4, 0);
Array AAA2 = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 4, 1);
Array BBB = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 4);
Array CCC = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new int[] { 4 } , new int[] { 0 } );
Array DDD = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new int[] { 4 });

int[] arr1 = (int[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 4);
int[] arr2 = (int[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new int[] { 4 }, new int[] { 0 });
Array arr3 = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new int[] { 4 }, new int[] { 1 });

Console.WriteLine("AAA.type: " + AAA.GetType());       \\ System.Int32[,]
Console.WriteLine("AAA2.type: " + AAA2.GetType());     \\ System.Int32[,]
Console.WriteLine("BBB.type: " + BBB.GetType());       \\ System.Int32[]
Console.WriteLine("CCC.type: " + CCC.GetType());       \\ System.Int32[]
Console.WriteLine("DDD.type: " + DDD.GetType());       \\ System.Int32[]
Console.WriteLine("---");
Console.WriteLine("arr1.type: " + arr1.GetType());     \\ System.Int32[]
Console.WriteLine("arr2.type: " + arr2.GetType());     \\ System.Int32[]
Console.WriteLine("arr3.type: " + arr3.GetType());     \\ System.Int32[*]
```

The question I can't find an answer to is: **how do I pass an Array type to my method call, without the conversion type error**? Error is thrown by this call:

```
NAMESPACE.myFunction("", arr3)
                         ^
                         Cannot convert from 'System.Array' to 'int[*]'
```

Comment: exposing an API with a non-vector typed array is ... just asking for pain. That isn't a thing that you can cleanly express in C#; what is `NAMESPACE.myFunction`? is this a third party thing? can you change the signature, or request it be changed?

Comment: note: if the API is instance based, not static based, you *might* be able to cheat by using `dynamic`...

Comment: You can't keep the C# compiler happy.  Use ildasm.exe to decompile the assembly, edit the IL and change the argument to Array, put it back together with ilasm.exe.  If this is likely to change soon then you do want to contact the author to get this right.

Comment: @MarcGravell, it is a third party thing, called by National Instruments TestStand passing an `Array of Numbers (Int32)`. Unfortunately, we'd like to move away from TestStand, so I'm trying to call it from a c# app, instead.
Under all points of view, I don't see it changing soon, I can't get hold of the developer/maintainer, so it is sealed third party for me.

Comment: @MarcGravell, the `dynamic` solution is reporting this, instead: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[*]' to type 'System.Int32[]'.`